# Seperate XML content from a single XML file using XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have a XML file which contains multiple XML nodes. I would like to separate two XML notes and store them in separate variables. How would I write this functionality with XQuery? I have added my XML file below. Inside the XML file I have a `division` root element, `Dive` and `top-song` are two child elements. Now I want to read the `Dive` XML content in one variable and `top-song` content in another variable. Can any one please help me to sort out this issue?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <division>
     <Dive ID="2"><!-- I want this node in one variable -->
      <DiverFName>Joe</DiverFName>
      <DiverLName>Diver</DiverLName>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Divedate>1998-03-30</Divedate>
      <Country ID="1">Bahamas</Country>
      <City ID="2">Freeport</City>
      <Place ID="2">
        <Site>South Pass</Site>
        <Lat>24.865062</Lat>
        <Lon>-77.871094</Lon>
      </Place>
      <Divetime>36.00</Divetime>
      <Depth Scale="METRIC">5.48</Depth>
      <Buddy IDs="2" Names="Tim Diver" />
      <Comments>Great dive, saw 5 Caribbean Reef Sharks.  Performed compass navigation skills for Scuba Diver certification.</Comments>
      <Water>Salt</Water>
      <Entry>Boat</Entry>
      <Divetype>Research</Divetype>
      <Tanktype>Alu</Tanktype>
      <Tanksize>11.43</Tanksize>
      <PresS>179.26</PresS>
      <PresE>82.73</PresE>
      <Gas>Air</Gas>
      <Weather>Clear</Weather>
      <UWCurrent>Medium Current</UWCurrent>
      <MarineLife>
        <Animal>
            <Type>Nurse Shark</Type>
            <Abundance>1</Abundance>
            <Size>3 ft</Size>
            <Description>Dormant on the bottom, not swimming.</Description>
            <Image>
                <Filename></Filename>
                <Path></Path>
                <Caption></Caption>
            </Image>
        </Animal>
        <Animal>
            <Type>Blue Tang Surgeonfish</Type>
            <Abundance>25+</Abundance>
            <Size>4 in</Size>
            <Description>Blue with white "scalpel" near base </descreption>
            <Image>
                <Filename></Filename>
                <Path></Path>
                <Caption></Caption>
            </Image>
        </Animal>
      </MarineLife>
    </Dive>
<top-song><!-- I want this node in another variable -->
 <title >Try Again</title>
  <artist >Aaliyah</artist>
  <weeks last="2008-06-17">
    <week>2008-06-17</week>
  </weeks>
  <album> The
  Album</album>
  <released>February 29, 20008</released>
  <formats>
    <format>CD</format>
    <format>12 single</format>
  </formats>
  <recorded>january2012</recorded>
  <genres>
    <genre>R&amp;B</genre>
  </genres>
  <lengths>
    <length>4:04</length>
  </lengths>
  <label>Blackground</label>
  <writers>
    <writer></writer>
    <writer></writer>
  </writers>
  <producers>
    <producer></producer>
  </producers>
  <descr>
   <p>hai hello</p>
  </descr>
</top-song>
</division>
```

Comment: Please share your code, even if broken..

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish on a high level, but you can select those elements with some simple XQuery/Xpath:

```
let $dive := doc('mydoc.xml')/division/Dive
let $top-song := doc('mydoc.xml')/division/top-song
```

However, just looking at the document it's clear that these two elements are in totally unrelated schemas, and as a general recommendation for MarkLogic, they should probably each be separated before ingestion and inserted as separate documents.